# mongoDB, strongly typed collection using C# oficial driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, insert

I'm learning MongoDB and I want to try it with using C#. Is it possible to operate on strongly typed MongoDB documents using C# official MongoDB driver?

I have classes `Album` and `Photo`:

```
public class Album : IEnumerable<Photo> 
    {
        [Required]
        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [BsonElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("owner")]
        public string Owner { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("title_photo")]
        public Photo TitlePhoto { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("pictures")]
        public List<Photo> Pictures { get; set; }

        //rest of the class code
    }

public class Photo : IEquatable<Photo>
    {
        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name;

        [BsonElement("description")]
        public string Description;

        [BsonElement("path")]
        public string ServerPath;

        //rest of the class code
    }
```

I want to insert a new document into a collection `albums` in the `test` database. I don't want to operate on `BsonDocument`, but I would prefer to use strongly typed `Album`. I thought it would be something like:

```
IMongoClient client = new MongoClient();
IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("test");
IMongoCollection<Album> collection = database.GetCollection<Album>("album");
var document = new Album
            {
                Name = album.Name,
                Owner = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
                Description = album.Description,
                TitlePhoto = album.TitlePhoto,
                Pictures = album.Pictures
            };
collection.InsertOne(document);
```

But it gives me the following error:

> An exception of type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException' occurred
>   in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Command insert failed: error parsing element 0
>   of field documents :: caused by :: wrong type for '0' field, expected
>   object, found 0: [].

What am I doing wrong and if it's possible to achieve?

Comment: [It may be help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273145/Using-MongoDB-with-the-Official-Csharp-Driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the driver is treating your object as a BSON array because it implements `IEnumerable<Photo>`. The database is expecting a BSON document instead. You'll get a similar error if you try to insert, for example, an `Int32` into a collection.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to configure the serializer to treat your `Album` object as a BSON document. The static `BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry` property shows the driver is choosing to use [`EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer<Album,Photo>`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Serializers_EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer_1.htm) as `Album`'s serializer by default.

Removing the `IEnumerable<Photo>` implementation from `Album` causes the driver to serialize with [`BsonClassMapSerializer<Album>`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_BsonClassMapSerializer_1.htm), producing a BSON document. While it works, the downside is `Album` is no longer enumerable; application consumers will need to enumerate the `Pictures` property.

Adding the `IEnumerable<Photo>` implementation back in, then forcing the aforementioned serializer (using the `[BsonSerializer(typeof(BsonClassMapSerializer<Album>))]` attribute) results in:

> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Based on the stack trace (referring to `BsonSerializerAttribute.CreateSerializer`), the object the message refers to appears to be something serialization-related, not the data objects themselves (I defined parameterless constructors for both). I don't know if there's a way around this problem with further configuration, or if the driver just won't allow an `IEnumerable` to be used this way.

Comment: Thanks for the very constructive comment. I had no idea that `IEnumerable` was the problem. For now, I've solved the issue by removing that interface and I've implemented my own iterator, cause I really only need to get through all consecutive photos.